# MYSQL INET_NTOA With IP in Mybb

Tags: mysql

I have a Mybb forum set up and have noticed the IPs stored in the database are in a packed format. `Example 4f42c2c3`

I've tried to unpack one of them using the following query

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(lastip) 
From db_1.amxbans_amxadmins 
T1 INNER JOIN  db_2.mybb_users T2 ON T1.uid = T2.uid 
WHERE T2.uid = 145
```

which returned 0.0.0.0

Running the query without INET_NTOA returns the ip in packed form as normal...

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select inet_ntoa(conv('4f42c2c3', 16, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't work at first, changed it to this inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(lastip), 16, 10))